# Why isn't this updating the positions in the database when the other one does

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

So I am trying to change the order of my references under my reference Heading, for I have multiple of them under one, but the problem here is that I cannot change the order of them. If I just put the code straight into phpmyadmin it works but it doesn't seem to work trough here for some reason.

And I have no idea why. I tried try catch but it didn't give me any errors

Here are my methods

```
public function changeHeadingPositions(array $positions) {

    $count = count($positions);

    $return = '';

    for ($i=1; $i <= $count ; $i++) { 
        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->headingsTable . ' SET position = :pos WHERE headingID = :headingID';
        $sql = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $sql->execute(['pos' => $i, 'headingID' => (int)$positions[$i-1]]);

        $return = $return . ' Otsikon ' . $positions[$i-1] . ' sijainti on nyt ' . $i . '<br>';
    }

    return $return;

}

public function changeReferencePositions(array $positions) {

    $count = count($positions);

    $return = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->refsTable . ' SET position = :pos WHERE refID = :refID';
        $sql = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $sql->execute(['pos' => $i, 'refID' => (int)$positions[$i-1]]);

        $return = $return . ' Referenssin ' . $positions[$i-1] . ' sijainti on nyt ' . $i . '<br>';
    }

    return $return;
}
```

And Here is my code that I use to call it

```
declare(strict_types =1);
include 'includes/class-autoloader.inc.php';

$array0 = array(4, 3, 2, 1);

$object = new Reference();
echo $object->changeHeadingPositions($array0);

$array1 = array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

echo $object->changeReferencePositions($array1);
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that one of those functions works and the other doesn't?  Have you enabled error messages to check if anything is failing?

Comment: Yeah, and it gives me back no errors :/

Comment: Which one works? Also check you have `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` for your database connection to ensure errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I fixed it by adding `` these on the ends of the refsTable which is named as "references" in the database.

So now the code looks like this.

```
public function changeReferencePositions(array $positions) {

        $count = count($positions);

        $return = '';

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

            $sql = 'UPDATE `' . $this->refsTable . '` SET position = :pos WHERE refID = :refID';
            $sql = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $sql->execute(['pos' => $i, 'refID' => (int)$positions[$i-1]]);

            $return = $return . ' Referenssin ' . $positions[$i-1] . ' sijainti on nyt ' . $i . '<br>';

        }

        return $return;
    }
```

It seems that MySQL didn't like the references without these `` quotes